# Hide iframe if src is http:// without link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I need to hide the `iframe` if the

```
src is "http://".
```

What I tried to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    if ( $('iframe[src][src="http://"]') )
        document.getElementById('iframe').style.display='none';
    else
        document.getElementById('iframe').style.display='block';
</script>
```

and html

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="url" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide iframes with only `src="http://"`, you can do this with jQuery and some regex.

**Note:** In Chrome, the src of "http://" is reported as "http:". In Safari and Chrome on iOS it is reported as "http:/". To account for this difference a simple regex can be used.

```js
$('iframe').each(function() {
  var src = this.src.toLowerCase();
  if (/^http:[\/]{0,2}$/i.test(src)) {
    $(this).hide();
  } else {
    $(this).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1. http://<br><iframe id="iframe" src="http://"></iframe><br>
2. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png<br><iframe id="iframe" src="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png"></iframe><br>
```

---

If you additionally want to hide iframes with `src=""` or no src set, or `src="https://"`, you can use the code below. The conditional `src === self.location.href` tests for `src=""`. The regex `/^https?:[\/]{0,2}\w/i` tests for "http(s)://" plus one word character. If not found, the iframe is hidden. Non-http(s) src'd iframes are hidden too.

```js
$('iframe').each(function() {
  var src = this.src.toLowerCase();
  if (src === self.location.href || !/^https?:[\/]{0,2}\w/i.test(src)) {
    $(this).hide();
  } else {
    $(this).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1. http://<br><iframe id="iframe" src="http://"></iframe><br>
2. https://<br><iframe id="iframe" src="https://"></iframe><br>
3. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png<br><iframe id="iframe" src="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png"></iframe><br>
4. ""<br><iframe id="iframe" src=""></iframe><br>
5. (blank)<br><iframe id="iframe"></iframe><br>
6. "a.htm"<br><iframe id="iframe" src="a.htm"></iframe><br>
7. src<br><iframe id="iframe" src></iframe><br>
```

Comment: Kindly run the snippets above with the battery of iframe tests

Comment: thanks, working properly. But I need also if the "src" has no value, just src.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your jQuery selector to `iframe[src="http://"]` or a better solution is to use CSS to hide your iframe.

When you are working with style related things you should always use CSS instead of javascript.

```css
iframe[src="http://"] {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<iframe src="http://"></iframe>
<iframe src=""></iframe>
```

Comment: Fixing the selector won't help, since `$()` always returns a jQuery object, and the condition will always pass. You've to check the length of the returned object. The CSS solution is nice though,

Comment: @Teemu yes, but my answer is about use CSS instead javascript code, I think that style related things should always done with CSS ;-)

Comment: Why not add that small detail to the answer, and earn some rep?

Comment: This is so much cleaner, wish would have found years ago instead of using javascript!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
    function checkFrame(){
        if($('iframe[src][src="http://"]'))
            document.getElementById('iframe').style.display='none';
        else
            document.getElementById('iframe').style.display='block';
    }
</script>
```

and call the function whenever you need to check it. Perhaps the `onLoad` parameter on the body tag?

But I must ask, why "else" display it, it by default would be displayed.

Also, what if the value is null?

Well, hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for help. This way also doesnt working and you are right, by default it should be shown. Do you have time to help me out using google remote desktop?

Comment: Absolutely, go ahead and get it started, and copy & paste your access code here.

Comment: can you write to my email please: abzalktl95 [at] gmail  [dot] com

Answer (score 1):

You could attach an `onload` handler to your `iframe`:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
iframe.onload = function() {
    if(iframe.src == 'http://') {
        iframe.style.display = 'none'; 
    } else {
        iframe.style.display = '';//default
    }
}
```